# How to get the image from html file and display by webview in android

Tags: android, html, webview

In asset folder I have store the many html file and many images. I want to read  the particular image which is having the image tag in html page and want to  display by webview in android.

Here in this html page I want to read this image EqnA01.png and wants to  display on the screen by webview.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css"  />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Factoring Formulas</h1>
<img  border="0" src="EqnA01.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem? And what is the question?